# "Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab." error in QT while trying to implement simple MVC

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a simple MVC in QT. The goal is to have a single rendering widget, a model, and a controller. The controller will be an abstract base class with a "render" method, so each controller knows how to draw its model given something to paint on. I've built a very simple sample of what I'm trying to accomplish, but when debugging, the following error is displayed almost immediately:

**Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.**

I've stripped away as much as I could to reproduce the error. Although the code will run and exit with what's displayed below, attempting to create the RenderWidget will lead to several errors, including a Segmentation Fault crash (in debug mode).

Any help would be appreciated. I've included the minimum code required to reproduce this error below. This was made in an empty QT Widget project **without** forms.

## Update 1

I've spent some more time fighting with this error and I've narrowed it down further. I've trimmed the code down even further and moved it all into a single Main.cpp file, as per Mitch's suggestion. The error appears if you place a breakpoint in the Main method and step into the MainWindow constructor.

### Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>

class RenderWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RenderWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

RenderWidget::RenderWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    RenderWidget* m_renderArea;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_renderArea = new RenderWidget(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: That's a lot of files... it is possible to have a Qt C++ example that is contained within one main.cpp file, if you just add `#include "main.moc"` at the bottom of the file. It would make other users much more inclined to try out your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was either a bug with the version of QT I had installed, or with the debugger I was using. The problem was present even if I created a new project. After installing QT 5.3 and getting the newest version of Debugging Tools for Windows, the error appears to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove or implement your constructor in Controller:

```
//Controller();
```

or

```
Controller() {}
```

Moreover, in `ControllerA`, you should also call base class:

```
ControllerA::ControllerA()
   : Controller()
{
}
```

Finally, `ui_renderArea` is not initialized.